# Liferay 6.2: get portlet's custom title from look and feel

Tags: liferay, look-and-feel

I´d like to get the custom title from the "Look and feel" fields in a concrete jsp of my portlet. Is it possible? How could I do that?

Comment: Try getting it from portletDisplay object which you can get from themeDisplay context object. e.g`themeDisplay=(ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getTitle()`

Comment: Just like that! :)

The thing is, I was trying to establish a custom title for a portlet that had it by properties. I finally changed the approach and ended up using the border option of the portlet controls.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya That code does not return the Custom Title. Do you have a snippet for getting the Custom Title in the template?